# difference between *head and (*head) pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, head

The following is a sample code, not the working one. 
I just want to know the difference between `*head` and `(*head)` in pointers in C.

```
int  insert(struct node **head, int data) {

      if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        // what is the difference between (*head)->next and *head->next ?
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->data = data;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` has lower precedence than `->` so

```
*head->next
```

would be equivalent to

```
*(head->next)
```

If you want to dereference `head` you need to place the dereference operator `*` inside brackets

```
(*head)->next
```

Comment: *(head)->next? (*head)->next!

Comment: @PeterMiehle Thanks, that was a rather important/embarrassing typo!

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between a+b and (a+b), but there's a big difference between a+b*c and (a+b)*c. It's the same with *head and (*head) ... (*head)->next uses the value of *head as a pointer, and accesses its next field. *head->next is equivalent to *(head->next) ... which isn't valid in your context, because head isn't a pointer to a struct node.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because of operator [precedence of C](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

`->` has higher precedence than `*`

---

## Execution

**For `*head->next`**

```
 *head->next  // head->next work first ... -> Precedence than *
      ^
 *(head->next) // *(head->next) ... Dereference on result of head->next 
 ^
```

---

**For `(*head)->next`**

```
 (*head)->next  // *head work first... () Precedence
    ^
 (*head)->next  // (*head)->next ... Member selection via pointer *head 
        ^
```

Comment: hey and also whats the difference between head->next and *head->next ??

Comment: Both are different as `head->next` will not be dereferenced. And `*head->next` work as -> `*(head->next)`, So always use `()` to ensure correct execution.

Comment: @RahulReddy: Have you understood ? Feel free to ask query.

Answer (score 0):

`->` has [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) over `*`(Dereference) operator so you **need parenthesis** `()` around `*head` **to overwrite precedence**. So Correct is `(*head)->next` as you `head` is pointer to pointer of struct.

`*head->next`  same as  `*(head->next)` That is wrong (give you compiler error, actually **syntax error**)

Comment: whats the difference between (*head)->next and head->next

Comment: @RahulReddy `(*head)->next` is correct where ad `head->next` is error, syntax error as head is pointer to pointer and doesn't have next as member.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference.

Usually.

In this case however, it's used to overcome a problem with operator precedence: `->` binds more tightly than `*`, so without the parentheses `*head->next` works out to the equivalent of `*(head->next)`.

Since this is not what is desired, `*head` is parenthesised in order for the operations to happen in the correct order.